# How to assign a folder a mount point in VB

Tags: vb.net, directory, mount-point

I hope I worded that right...
Anyway... while writing a VB program I noticed something. In the file explorer under `C:\Users\Username\` you see folders like `My Documents` and `My Pictures`. When you look at them in command prompt, you see that they are actually called `Documents` and `Pictures`. Weird.

Now lets say I want to make a folder, in VB, named `My Files`, but I want it to point to the actual folder `Files`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for this but I've heard you can achieve it through [Create A Special Folder In Windows Explorer](http://a2ztricks.blogspot.com/2008/04/create-special-folder-in-windows.html). I would definitely backup your registry first.

You can make "virtual folders" with [Namespace Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144095%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's a pain with .NET. There are components like [EZNamespaceExtensions.Net](http://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm) that make the process a little easier.